# Android training for FragmentBasics won't import into AS 1.5.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In trying to get the hang of `Fragment`, I imported into Android Studio 1.5.1 the unzipped folder `FragmentBasics` after extracting the downloaded file `FragmentBasics.zip` to that Folder.

Now I have Gradle problems and I have no clue what to do to be able to run the app. I don't know that the .zip file is from Eclipse as the message suggests.

I did move the folder `FragmentBasics` to C:\Users\Dov because of the space in "Google Drive" but got same error.

---

Gradle project sync failed . Basic functionality (e.g., editing, debugging) will not work properly.

Failed to sync gradle project 'FragmentBasics'
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-15' in: C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Open Android SDK Manager

## ECLIPSE ANDROID PROJECT IMPORT SUMMARY

### Risky Project Location:

The tools *should* handle project locations in any directory. However,
due to bugs, placing projects in directories containing spaces in the
path, or characters like ", ' and &, have had issues. We're working to
eliminate these bugs, but to save yourself headaches you may want to
move your project to a location where this is not a problem.

C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\FragmentBasics

```
               -
```

### Replaced Jars with Dependencies:

The importer recognized the following .jar files as third party
libraries and replaced them with Gradle dependencies instead. This has
the advantage that more explicit version information is known, and the
libraries can be updated automatically. However, it is possible that
the .jar file in your project was of an older version than the
dependency we picked, which could render the project not compileable.
You can disable the jar replacement in the import wizard and try again:

android-support-v4.jar => com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0

### Moved Files:

Android Gradle projects use a different directory structure than ADT
Eclipse projects. Here's how the projects were restructured:

- AndroidManifest.xml => app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
- res\ => app\src\main\res\
- src\ => app\src\main\java\

### Next Steps:

You can now build the project. The Gradle project needs network
connectivity to download dependencies.

### Bugs:

If for some reason your project does not build, and you determine that
it is due to a bug or limitation of the Eclipse to Gradle importer,
please file a bug at http://b.android.com with category
Component-Tools.

(This import summary is for your information only, and can be deleted
after import once you are satisfied with the results.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed sdk 15 but then had problems with Gradle griping about
`gradle-wrapper.properties` file having a line with

`gradle-2.8-all.zip` that needed to be changed to

`gradle-2.1-all.zip`, so I edited `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to contain `2.1` instead of `2.8`.

Message said after making change, re-import project. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Before importing I only removed following line from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Worked with FragmentsBasics.zip in Android Studio 2.3.3